# Binding WPF int and int?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have template column like this. When I set property in other column I regenerate columns and invoke UpdateLayout for a grid and after that my combobox doesn't bind property of int but when this property is int? all working ok. Please help me to explain this behaviour.

```
<TemplateColumnMetadata Name="User" Header="User"  MinWidth="150">
    <TemplateColumnMetadata.ColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox    
                ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Users}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                SelectedValuePath="Id"
                SelectedValue="{Binding UserId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"       
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsCellEditable}">
            <ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    <TemplateColumnMetadata.ColumnTemplate>           
<TemplateColumnMetadata>
```

**1. This code works**

```
public int? UserId
{
    get { return Model.UserId; }
    set
    {
        Model.UserId= value.Value;
    }
}
```

**2. This code doesn't work**

```
public int UserId
{
    get { return Model.UserId; }
    set
    {
        Model.UserId= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Int? = nullable int. null value is allowed here. Int -> null value is not allowed

Comment: What type is Your Model.Users?

Comment: At first binding works for int, this issue reproduce after regenerate columns

Comment: Model.Users is Class

Comment: I need bind UserId with int type

Comment: What is Model.Users derived from? What type does it enable to be an itemssource?

Comment: Binding works ok and type of Id in Users is int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured because null value went from xaml and binding got broken. So it worked for int? but it didn't work for int.